# ssh to open a file on a remote machine in perl

Tags: perl, text, ssh

I am having problems with ssh'ing to a remote machine and open a text file on that machine using Perl. I am currently tailing the file as seen below,

```
my $remote_filename = '/export/home/fsv/sample.txt';
my $remote_host = 'bs16-s1.xyz.com';

my $cmd = "ssh -l $sshUser $remote_host tail -f $remote_filename |";

open  $inFile, $cmd or die "Couldn't spawn [$cmd]: $!/$?";
```

The connection times out and I see that file is not even close to being opened. I tried using Net::SSH and Remote::FIle as well with no avail. It would be great if I could get some assistance on this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? ssh timing out? What does that have to do with Perl?

Comment: And what does "file is not even close to being opened" mean?

Comment: I am sorry for being cryptic, I don't see any progress with the script execution. I have break the execution since the script stops responding.

Comment: I suspect it actually blocks later in the program (e.g. when you try to read from `$inFile`).

Comment: I figured it out, I stopped tailing it and did a 'cat', it worked. Thanks for the assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

You are actually blocking later in the program than you claim. Specifically, you block where you read from `$inFile` until the handle returns EOF, which is why `ssh` exits, which is when `tail` exits. Since `tail -f` never exits (unless terminated by a signal), you never exit either. That's why switching to `cat` worked.